# Drupal - How to change/remove meta tags

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, meta-tags

How can I remove or change existing meta tags in Drupal 7? In drupal 6 there was `drupal_set_header` or something like that, but Drupal 7 doesn't know about that.

Is there any way I can do this without having an extra module? Currently I have 2 meta description tags, and I don't want that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement [hook_html_head_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_html_head_alter/7) to change existing head tags in Drupal 7.

Also you can use the [drupal_add_html_head()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head/7) and [drupal_add_html_head_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_html_head_link/7) functions in place of the old `drupal_set_header()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function your-themme_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {

$remove = array(
        'apple-touch-icon57',
        'apple-touch-icon72',
        'apple-touch-icon114'
);

foreach ($remove as $key) {
    if (isset($head_elements[$key])) {
        unset($head_elements[$key]);
    }
}   

//add
$appleIcon57px = array('#tag' => 'link', '#type' => 'html_tag', '#attributes' => array('rel' => 'apple-touch-icon', 'href' => '/misc/AMU-NUMERIQUE-ICONE-57.png', 'type' => 'image/png', 'media' => 'screen and (resolution: 163dpi)'),);
$appleIcon72px = array('#tag' => 'link','#type' => 'html_tag', '#attributes' => array('rel' => 'apple-touch-icon', 'href' => '/misc/AMU-NUMERIQUE-ICONE-72.png', 'type' => 'image/png', 'media' => 'screen and (resolution: 132dpi)'),);
$appleIcon114px = array('#tag' => 'link','#type' => 'html_tag', '#attributes' => array('rel' => 'apple-touch-icon', 'href' => '/misc/AMU-NUMERIQUE-ICONE-114.png', 'type' => 'image/png', 'media' => 'screen and (resolution: 326dpi)'),);


$head_elements['apple-touch-icon57']=$appleIcon57px;
$head_elements['apple-touch-icon72']=$appleIcon72px;
$head_elements['apple-touch-icon114']=$appleIcon114px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `hook_menu()` to add head tags in Drupal 7.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 * @return array
 */
function module-name_menu() {
  $items['add-metatags'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'custom_metatags',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  return $items;
}

function custom_metatags() {

  $html_head = array(
    'description' => array(
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'name' => 'description',
        'content' => 'Enter your meta description here.',
      ),
    ),
    'keywords' => array(
      '#tag' => 'meta',
      '#attributes' => array(
        'name' => 'keywords',
        'content' => 'Enter your meta keywords here.',
      ),
    ),
  );
  foreach ($html_head as $key => $data) {
    drupal_add_html_head($data, $key);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please provide explanation to the answer